# double submitting on sql query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2, ejs

I have a form where I am inserting product details into my db table. however, for some reason, it is double submitting. I cannot figure out why for the life of me. here's the code both front end and back end:

front-end:

```html
<form method="GET" action="/addProducts" style="border: 2px solid black">
   <h1>Add a product</h1>
   <fieldset>
      <label for="productName">Product Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="item" name="item" placeholder="Candy Socks" style="border: 1px solid black" required>
      <label for="productPrice">Price:</label>
      <input type="text" id="price" name="price" placeholder="$9.99" style="border: 1px solid black" required>
      <!-- <label for="productCategory">Category:</label>
         <input type="text" id="category" name="category" placeholder="Socks" style="border: 1px solid black"equired> -->
      <label for="productCategory">SIZES (OPTIONAL):</label>
      <!-- <input type="text" id="size" name="size" placeholder="(EX) XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL" style="border: 1px solid black"> -->
      <label for="check-1">Extra Small</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="extra-small" value="xs" onclick="xsFunction()">
      <style>
         .hide { display: none; }
      </style>
      <span id="smallPrice" class="hide" >Price $ <input type="text" id="small"></span>
      <script>
         function xsFunction() {
           // document.getElementById("xs").innerHTML = '<label for="check-1">XS Price ($)</label><input type="text" name="xs" id="extra-small">';
           document.getElementById("smallPrice").classList.toggle('hide');
         }
      </script>
      <p id="xs"></p>
      <label for="check-1">Small</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="small" value="small" onclick="sFunction()">
      <script>
         function sFunction() {
           document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = '<label for="check-1">SMALL Price ($)</label><input type="text" name="s" id="small">';
         }
      </script>
      <p id="s"></p>
      <label for="check-1">Medium</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="medium" value="medium" onclick="mFunction()">
      <script>
         function mFunction() {
           document.getElementById("m").innerHTML = ' <label for="check-1">MEDIUM Price ($)</label><input type="text" name="m" id="medium">';
         }
      </script>
      <p id="m"></p>
      <label for="check-1">Large</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="large" value="large" onclick="lFunction()">
      <script>
         function lFunction() {
           document.getElementById("l").innerHTML = '<label for="check-1">LARGE Price ($)</label> <input type="text" name="l" id="large">';
         }
      </script>
      <p id="l"></p>
      <label for="check-1">Extra Large</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="extra-large" value="xl" onclick="xlFunction()">
      <script>
         function xlFunction() {
           document.getElementById("xl").innerHTML = ' <label for="check-1">XL Price ($)</label><input type="text" name="xl" id="xl">';
         }
      </script>
      <p id="xl"></p>
      <label for="divisionCategory">CATEGORY (OPTIONAL):</label>
      <select name="category" id="">
         <% if(data.length){ 
            for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>
         <option value="<%= data[i].CATEGORIES %>"><%= data[i].CATEGORIES %></option>
         <% }
            }else{ %>
         <% } %>
      </select>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
      <label for="bio">Description:</label>
      <textarea id="bio" name="description" placeholder="Beautiful and fun Candy Socks!" style="border: 1px solid black" required></textarea>
   </fieldset>
   <button id="submitButton" type="submit">NEXT</button>
</form>
```

backend:

```js
var addProducts =
    "insert into PRODUCTS ( ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SIZES, DIVISION, XS, S, M, L, XL ) VALUES ('" +
    req.query.item +
    "', '" +
    req.query.description +
    "', '" +
    req.query.price +
    "', '" +
    size +
    "', '" +
    req.query.category +
    "', '" +
    req.query.xs +
    "', '" +
    req.query.s +
    "', '" +
    req.query.m +
    "', '" +
    req.query.l +
    "', '" +
    req.query.xl +
    "' )";
ibmdb.open(req.session.ibmdbconnDash, function(err, conn) {
    if (err) 
        return console.log(err);
    conn.query(addProducts, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        conn.close(function() {
            console.log("closed the function /add-products");
        });

        var getProductDetails = "select * from products where ITEM = '" + req.query.item + "'";
        ibmdb.open(req.session.ibmdbconnDash, function(err, conn) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            conn.query(getProductDetails, function(err, dataset2) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

                var productAddedValue = ""
                console.log(gianluca)
                res.render("add-products2", {
                    page_title: "add-products2",
                    data: dataset2,
                    userName: req.session.username,
                    FN: req.session.firstname,
                    LN: req.session.lastname,
                    CO: req.session.company,
                    productAddedValue: productAddedValue,
                });

                conn.close(function() {
                    console.log("closed the function /add-products p2");
                });
            });
        });



    });
});
```

I know how messy this code is, I apologize. I am in the mists of fixing it up. but still double submitting which is so strange. I see doubles of every product when I hit submit. thanks for the help!

Comment: A form won't submit twice by itself. Is there JavaScript that submits the form in addition to the automatic submission?

Comment: You should use parameters in the SQL query instead of concatenating strings, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Your form should use a post action instead of a get action.

Comment: not sure why, but changing it to POST worked... could you explain why?

Comment: and WHY a `ibmdb.open()` nested in a `ibmdb.open()` ?

Comment: @SimonDehaut I could have used one, I just did multiple because I copied and pasted from my other app... will change it tho for PROD

Comment: It makes sense of course when you think about it. When you submit to a page with a get, it posts and comes back with the data you posted as some query string. Since you are posting to an external form, that form is posted to and runs once on the server and then does a get with the data you posted on the way back from the server and runs again. When you do a post it just sends data, runs once and comes back without a get.

Comment: Good read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: @Chuma this helps a lot. thank you :)

Comment: Sure np. Glad to be of service